# MVC SMTP mail not sending

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, smtp

I have a MVC project that uses a remote SMTP service that works fine sending mail, when on the server, but when I load the project on my local machine and run it, it does not send mail.  What could be the problem???  Do I need to enable SMTP on my local development machine?

Comment: r you using iis, iis express or cassini?

Comment: The problem depends on the kind of error message that you get. We are not psychic. Provide the error message and your SMTP settings.

Comment: my suspiscion is ur using Cassini. Thats the web development server included in Visual Studio. Cassini cannot send email. IIS Express is the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC settings using a remote smtp server did work for some reason.

I was able to get it to work locally by using google's smtp server instead on port 587.

thank for the replies.